# Querying an HTTPS SOAP service fails in C#

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, https, .net-4.0

first of all, i know near to nothing about SOAP (and i really hoped i'd be lucky enough to stay away from it), so pardon my total ignorance.

I need to call (from the .NET 4 Framework) some functions on an old SOAP service made in Java but for some reason i am unable to do so and i don't understand why since everything worked on a test environment with HTTP inside a VPN.

I tried other solutions found here and online but nothing seems to work and i cannot access the log on the SOAP server to see exactly what goes wrong.

I know that the service works because SoapUI (version 5.7.0) can communicate with it without a problem.

In SoapUI, in the Outgoing WS-Security Configurations page i added these WSS Entries:

- Timestamp
- Signature
- Encryption

as told by the service provider, i don't know if it matters.

This is how the client used to work inside the test environment (with HTTP):

```
var myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
myBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Message;
myBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate;
myBinding.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.TripleDes;
myBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
var ei = EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("test");
var aec = new AddressHeaderCollection();
var ea = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://endpointurl/servicename"), ei, aec);
var client = new DonorportalServiceInsiel.DonorportalServicePortClient(myBinding, ea);
client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\cert1.p12"), "12345678");
client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\cert2.p12"), "12345678");
return client;
```

As i said, this code worked perfectly inside the test VPN environment.

Unfortunately when i had to move it into production the endpoint address changed, now it is not HTTP anymore, but it is HTTPS... according to the guys that provide this SOAP service nothing else has changed (beside the certificates for signing and encryption which i did update).

Since this code didn't work anymore i tried using the BasicHttpsBinding instead than BasicHttpBinding and i tried BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport and also BasicHttpsSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential, but nothing... i get this error: "An error was discovered processing the wsse:Security header".

As i said, unfortunately i do not have access to the log on the server side so i don't exactly know what's wrong. I read somewhere that perhaps the body of the message is not getting signed (why??) so i tried adding
client.Endpoint.Contract.ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.Sign;
and also
client.Endpoint.Contract.ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
but same error.

I even tried creating my own custom binding but since i don't know what i'm doing i had no success either.

Any help is appreciated.

So far i tried:

- Changing BasicHttpBinding to BasicHttpsBinding
- Changing the security mode from BasicHttpSecurityMode.Message to BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport and BasicHttpsSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential (with both BasicHttpBinding and BasicHttpsBinding)
- Trying to force the body signature with System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.Sign and System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign
- Create my own custom binding (but i don't know what i am doing, i tried to follow several examples online but i don't fully understand them)

Comment: What OS are you using?  What target project are you using? Did you load certificate on both client and server?  SOAP is xml response from a HTTP/HTTPS connection.  What line is failing?  HTTPS uses TLS to establish encryption between client and server.  TLS is performed before the HTTP request is sent.  TLS the server sends a certificate block with possible certificate names.  The client than looks up the names in the stores.  You code is specifying a specific certificate name.  So either your machine cannot handle the certificate, or the server isn't sending the certificate name.

Comment: Hello @jdweng thank you for your comment. My OS is Windows 10, what do you mean with "what target project are you using"? It is a .NET Framework 4.7.2 Console project, don't know if this answers your question. As per the certificates, i'm using the ones they gave me. As i said, i know near to nothing about SOAP, i just know that before introducing HTTPS everything worked perfectly and i assumed all i needed to do was to use the BasicHttpsBinding and an https url. Oh btw, it gives me an exception when i use the client returned by this code to call the method i need to call on the webservice.

Comment: @jdweng 
If i use BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport i get this exception "An error was discovered processing the <wsse:Security> header"

If i used BasicHttpsSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential i get something that translated in English sounds like "An unsecured error or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner fault exception for the fault code and detail." and the Inner Exception is "An error was discovered processing the <wsse:Security> header."

Comment: You need to find the type of key in the certificate.  Most likely the certificate is TLS1.3 and the encryption mode has changed from SecurityAlgorithmSuite.TripleDes.  Starting in Net 4.7.2 TLS is performed by the operating system and not in Net.  The csproj file contains a parameter to use Net instead of OS.  Make sure you are using OS (and not Net).  You can open csproj file with notepad.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#switchsystemservicemodeldontenablesystemdefaulttlsversions

Comment: DES is not secure and probably the certificate is using newer encryption.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: I tried downgrading the project from .NET 4.7.2 to .NET 4.5.2, same errors. I didn't touch any default setting in the project file. As for TripleDES, i had to use it because that's what the test environment used. I have now changed it to "Default" but i still get the same errors.

Comment: BTW the certificate on the server uses SHA-256 with RSA encryption so i guess it is at least TLS 1.2

Comment: You said "according to the guys that provide this SOAP service nothing else has changed (beside the certificates for signing and encryption which i did update)."  So isn't it possible the encryption mode changed?  Your code has "myBinding.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.TripleDes;"  Check with vendor and see what you are supposed to be using.

Comment: You have to use Net 4.7.1 or later. You are using Windows 10.  What type of machine?  Is it a cell phone?  The kernel may not support the SHA-256.  You may need to update the kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after many failed attempts i finally made it work.
Since the version in the test environment (which used HTTP with BasicHttpBinding) did work, i compared the binding elements with the production environment (which uses HTTPS) and found that if i use the BasicHttpsBinding the package was not encrypted (i guess because it is already encrypted via HTTPS).

Unfortunately the legacy code on the server, beside using outdated and insecure encryption standards, completely ignored the fact that we were using HTTPS and required the package to be encrypted anyways which made the whole thing fail.

I didn't have access to the server logs so i couldn't figure out what was wrong since it just gave me a generic "*An error was discovered processing the wsse:Security header*" without telling me exactly what was the problem. Since SOAP has, like, 1000 different configurations and options it was quite hard for me to understand what exactly the legacy code on the server didn't like even after several hours/days of failed attempts.

So, as i said, to figure out what was wrong i compared the two bindings and found out that the Security Element was different.

This is the code i used to compare the two bindings:

```
var httpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
httpBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Message;
httpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate;
httpBinding.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.TripleDes;
httpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
var httpElements = httpBinding.CreateBindingElements();

var httpsBinding = new BasicHttpsBinding();
httpsBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential; // Note that BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Message is not available with BasicHttpsBinding
httpsBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate;
httpsBinding.Security.Message.AlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.TripleDes;
httpsBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024;
var httpsElements = httpsBinding.CreateBindingElements();
```

I then compared the 3 elements inside the httpElements collection with the 3 elements inside the httpsElements collection and found that the element with index 0 (the Security Binding Element) was different.

By simply adding this line after the code above i managed to make it work for the first time.

```
httpsElements[0] = httpElements[0];
```

This was of course a dirty little trick and i didn't like it, but now i knew that if i managed to recreate the Security Element of the BasicHttpBinding i would be able to create a Custom Binding that did work.

So, this is the final working code:

```
var customBinding = new CustomBinding();

var sbe = (AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement)SecurityBindingElement.CreateMutualCertificateBindingElement(MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10);
sbe.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.TripleDes;
sbe.MessageProtectionOrder = MessageProtectionOrder.SignBeforeEncryptAndEncryptSignature;
sbe.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.Lax;

customBinding.Elements.Add(sbe); // Security
customBinding.Elements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8)); // Message
customBinding.Elements.Add(new HttpsTransportBindingElement() { MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024 }); // Transport

var ei = EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("test");
var aec = new AddressHeaderCollection();
var ea = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://endpointurl/servicename"), ei, aec);

var client = new DonorportalServiceProduzione.DonorportalServicePortClient(customBinding, ea);
client.Endpoint.Contract.ProtectionLevel = System.Net.Security.ProtectionLevel.EncryptAndSign;
client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\cert1.p12"), "12345678");
client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\cert2.p12"), "");
return client;
```

To figure out the correct options of the SecurityBindingElement (sbe in the code above) i just pretty much copied the settings in the Security Element of the BasicHttpBinding (httpElements[0] in the code above) and now it works perfectly.

Sorry if the solution is long but i thought that it would have been helpful to explain how i understood what was wrong so that perhaps it can help someone else that finds himself or herself in my same situation, knows nothing about SOAP like me and doesn't know how to tackle the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know your requirements.  I believe the requirements are outdated and here is my justification

1. Net Library before Net 4.7.1 did not support all encryption algorithms.  You new certificate is not supported with older version of Net
2. You are using Windows 10 which supports all encryption modes
3. TLS 1.2 and 1.3 are only valid TLS versions.  Older version are not secure since hackers have broken the encryption mode
4. You are using Net 4.7.2 which is using OS for TLS, instead of Net.
5. Your certificate is SHA-256 (not SecurityAlgorithmSuite.TripleDes).  You should not be supporting older encryption modes that are vulnerable.
6. Previous testing is not longer valid if you must use newer encryption algorithms to be secure and to work with your new certificate.

Comment: It is very likely possible, from the information they provided they gave me a working example in java that uses these constants   
ENCRYPTION_SIGNATURE_ALGORYTM = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc"  
ENCRYPTION_KEY_TRANSPORT = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p"  
SIGNATURE_ALGORYTM = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"  
Unfortunately i cannot change this, as i said, it is an old webservice and it is unlikely they are going to change it just for me, is there any way to use outdated and unsafe algorithms?

Comment: The doesn't make a lot of sense.  TLS1.2 and 1,3 are the only valid SSL/TLS versions.  All others are disabled on windows due to security risks.  Microsoft did a security push in June 2019 and disabled other versions.  The industry gave everybody 5 years to stop using the other versions of SSL/TLS in 2014.  The Wiki link I provided shows which key encryption algorithms are valid in 1.2 and 1.3.  You shouldn't be testing something that is obsolete.  Nobody uses the algorithms any more.

Comment: Is it possible that the connection with the HTTPS server uses a valid certificate while, at the same time, the XML SOAP package itself is signed/encrypted with a TripleDes certificate? I don't know how SOAP works, but perhaps you can have a SOAP package with its own outdated signing/encryption while using a normal HTTPS connection to expose the service on the web.

Comment: Yes, but older encryption algorithms still are vulnerable.  Which certificate changed?  You may have two different certificate issues.   It looks like TLS is working when you get : jdweng If i use BasicHttpsSecurityMode.Transport i get this exception "An error was discovered processing the <wsse:Security> header".  The <wsse:Security> header error is the XML signature.